# I typed `scrapy version` but it trigger or load other spiders in the folder

Tags: scrapy

I'm relatively new to Scrapy, I just type `scrapy version` like below;
But it did trigger spiders in the folder.

Obviously, I have some spiders in development, for example one spider opens a Chrome web driver in the init method, just typing Scrapy version opens the Chrome browser. Why Scrapy is loading all the spiders in the folder? How to avoid this?

```
(django_corp_data):~/sherlockit$ scrapy version
['version']
corp_data.spiders.quote
version
Scrapy 1.8.0
```

Comment: I created a new virtual environment, install scrapy then just copied a couple of spiders from a different project to the spider's folder. then typed scrapy version, it is giving me an error about missing libraries that is being used by one of the spiders. It means just type scrapy version, scrapy is trying to load all the spiders in the directory. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I made a rookie mistake.

I created the spider using the following command `scrapy genspider quotes quotes.com`

The above command will create your spider as `class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider)`

If you just type `scrapy version` or `scrapy crawl` the scrapy framework will load all your `scrapy.Spider` classed spiders.

If you are building multiple spiders, create your spider using scrapy crawl template, like `scrapy genspider -t crawl quotes quotes.com` notice the class of your newly created spider. `class QuotesSpider(CrawlSpider)`

It took me about a day to figure the above, hope this will help someone.